# Knockout component: model data bound to component is empty due to anync ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, knockout.js

I have a knockout component (consists of **my-template** and **my-viewmodel**), say Component1. The template includes another component, say Component2.

```
<template id='my-template'>
  <span data-bind='text: title'></span>        //-->> this works
  <div data-bind="component: {name: Component2}">
        <span data-bind='text: title'></span1> // -->> this is empty
  <div>
</template>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
function my-viewmodel(){
     self.title = ko.observable();
     $.getJSON(someUrl).then(function(result){
         self.title(result);
     });
}
```

For the **first span** (outside Component2), the **title** looks fine, but for the **second span** (inside Component2), the **title** is always **empty**. What is wrong in the code above? Any idea of how to fix it to make the title appears inside Component2?

I can't imagine that this is due to AJAX because the title in the first span has the value; only the second span doesn't get it.  But **Note** that if I remove the $.getJSON, and simply assign **title** to some hard-coded string, and it works fine - both span(s) have the same correct value.

Is it possible that Component2 gets initialized even before the $.getJSON finishes? If so, how to make the initialization of Component2 delay until $.getJSON finishes?

======================

If you wonder why I have span inside Component2: it's just that Components2 is a tree, and the span inside it is actually some **ul** and **li** tags that Components 2 uses to render a tree.

Comment: Where is your definition of what `Component2` actually is?  Are you seeing any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Component2 is from some external lib. No, did not see any errors on the console. If I put "title" as some hard-coded string, then both the span(s) will have the correct value.

Comment: I believe the component binding replaces the "innerHTML".

Comment: Yes. Component2 consumes the innerHTML of the div element, and produces a tree out of it. Well, to be more precise, Component2 still leaves the innerHTML there, but it seems to add a lot of css to it, which is what I see after the page is rendered. But the thing is, if I create the "title" without using any anync stuff (like Ajax), then it works fine.

Comment: There should be some way of passing the `title` into the component - I don't think it will just find it on your main viewmodel

Comment: @James: no, it's just that. I tested it. Besides, as I said before, If i do not use ajax to create title, and instead hard-code the value of title in the ViewModel, then it works fine. So things definitely have something to do with async ajax.

Comment: Without seeing the code that makes up component2, it's going to be hard to diagnose

Comment: It could be a context issue. Try `$parent.title`.

Comment: Component2 is a big knockout module, and unfortunately I don't have the right to post it here.

Comment: @Simo We don't really want to see a huge component anyways. Can you create a simple component that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @CrimsonChris: tried that. I believe the context is correct. I used knockout context debugger to double check. And beside, title is in fact an array arr, and if I put the arr.length as the binding value, then it returns 0 in the second span, meaning the context is right. Just the content is empty. arr.length is not 0 in the first span though.

Comment: The DOM nodes inside your `Component2` div will be stripped out by knockout and will be replaced by `Component2` template output. So you should only see the output of Component2 template, not `<span data-bind='text: title'></span1>`.

Comment: @Dandy Then why when I did not use ajax, and simply set self.title("Hey it's me!") in the viewmodel, then it works?

Comment: @Simo We really need to know how `Component2` is consuming the span with the title. I'm assuming it's using [componentTemplateNodes](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-markup-into-components)?

Comment: @CrimsonChris: so, what the code in Components2 does is that it will *detach* the content of the div element, and uses it as the template to render the div itself. However, I still can't explain why it works when no ajax is used. And no, it's not componentTemplateNodes. It's something not even public.

Comment: That proprietary library is likely the problem.

Comment: Just got up again - morning all :)  you mention that in reality it's an array - have you tried it being an observableArray at all?